# Как передать две переменные в css?

Tags: javascript

У меня идет рандомный генератор чисел (два разных числа передаются в переменную `x` и `у`). После чего я их передаю `map.style.backgroundPosition = x + '%';  y + '%';`.
Но передаться только одна переменная, как передать значение и второй переменной?

Comment: Нужен пример вашего кода.

Comment: разделитель между изменениями должен быть пробел:

Comment: `map.style.backgroundPosition = x+'% '+y+'%';`

Comment: О, то что нужно было)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> map.style.backgroundPosition = x + '%';  y + '%';
> ```

```
map.style.backgroundPosition = `${x}% ${y}%`;
```

```
map.style.backgroundPosition = x + "% " + y + "%";
```